# WM_SETREDRAW blocks display of owner drawn Listview Header

Tags: listview, winapi, header, ownerdrawn

I followed advice for using WM_SETREDRAW instead of LockWindowUpdate () to suppress listview update while filling in items. I found my header line does not show after sending WM_SETREDRAW msg with true. InvalidateRect() and UpdateWindow() combination or RedrawWindow() fail to show the owner drawn Header. To show the Header line, I need to manually force a new WM_PAINT msg by resizing or scrolling the listview screen.
This behavior is limited to owner drawn Header. If I do not subclass the Header procedure, native Window procedure simply display the header line after WM_SETREDRAW msg is sent with true.
Can anyone suggest what is missing in my code?

Notes:

1. Using WM_SETREDRAW proved far more efficient than LockWindowUpdae().
   For a big list, it took 1.9 secs to fill in items and display them
   instead of 9.6 sec when using LockWindowUpdate(). I hope I can
   display the Header properly with WM_SETREDRAW to benefit from the
   better performance.
2. When Creating a listview without adding items (and not sending
   WM_SETREDRAW msg), native Windows procedure shows the Header, but
   the subclassed procedure dose not show it till I manually move or
   resize the window. Again InvalidRect()/UpdateWindow() have no effect.

Here is the code for subclassing:

```
static LONG_PTR   DefaultHeaderProc ;
static char* HeaderText[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                             "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T"} ;

LRESULT CALLBACK ListDlgProc (HWND hDlg,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
static HWND     hwndHeader ;
static HWND     hwndListView ;


switch (msg)  {

    case WM_INITDIALOG :

        hwndListView = GetDlgItem (hDlg,IDC_LISTVIEW) ;
        hwndHeader   = ListView_GetHeader (hwndListView) ;

        ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle (hwndListView,LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | 
                    LVS_EX_TRANSPARENTBKGND |LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT) ;

        SendMessage (hwndListView,LVM_SETBKCOLOR,0,(LPARAM) 0xE0E0E0) ;
        SendMessage (hwndListView,LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR,0,(LPARAM) 0xC00000) ;

        // Initialize the LVCOLUMN structure. 
        LVCOLUMN    LvColumn ;
        ZeroMemory (&LvColumn,sizeof (LVCOLUMN)) ;
        LvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_TEXT ; 
        LvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT ;
        LvColumn.cx = 63  ;

        // Add the columns 
        for (int i = 0 ; i < COLUMNS ; i++) { 
            LvColumn.pszText = HeaderText[i] ;
            LvColumn.iSubItem = i ; 
            if (ListView_InsertColumn(hwndListView,i,&LvColumn) == -1) 
                return false ; 
        } /* for (int i = 0 ; i < COLUMNS ; i++) */

        DefaultHeaderProc = SetWindowLongPtr (hwndHeader,GWLP_WNDPROC,
                                 (LONG_PTR) HeaderSubclassProc) ;
        SendMessage (hwndHeader,IDM_INIT,0,0L) ;
        return true ;

    case WM_DESTROY :
        SetWindowLongPtr (hwndHeader,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR) DefaultHeaderProc) ;
        SetWindowLongPtr (hwndListView,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR) DefaultListViewProc) ;
        ListView_DeleteAllItems (hwndListView) ;
        return 0 ;
       ;
```

Here is the code for WM_PAINT processing:

```
    case WM_PAINT :
        PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
        hDC = BeginPaint (hwnd,&ps) ;

        int DefDC = SaveDC (hDC) ;

        SelectObject (hDC,Font) ;
        SelectObject (hDC,Pen) ;
        SelectObject (hDC,Brush) ;
        SetBkMode (hDC,TRANSPARENT) ;

        for (int Btn = 0 ; Btn < 20 ; Btn++) {
            if (Btn == HBtn)
                continue ;
            Header_GetItemRect (hwnd,Btn,&rc) ;
            Rectangle (hDC,rc.left,rc.top,rc.right + 1,rc.bottom) ;
            DrawText (hDC,HeaderText[Btn],-1,&rc,DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER) ;
        } /* for (int Btn = 0 ; Btn < 20 ; Btn++) */

        if (HBtn > -1 ) {
            Header_GetItemRect (hwnd,HBtn,&rc) ;
            SelectObject (hDC,HPen) ;
            SelectObject (hDC,HBrush) ;
            Rectangle (hDC,rc.left + 1,rc.top + 1,rc.right,rc.bottom - 1) ;
            DrawText (hDC,HeaderText[HBtn],-1,&rc,DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER) ;
        } /* if (HLBtn > -1 ) */

        RestoreDC (hDC,DefDC) ;
        EndPaint (hwnd,&ps) ;
        return 0 ;
```

HBtn is the zere index of "hot" header column when mouse hover over the header

Comment: All you have shown is your drawing code, but you have not shown how you are subclassing the ListView header, or how you are populating the ListView items.

Comment: Try calling `InvalidateRect(header...)` after `SendMessage(list,WM_SETREDRAW,TRUE,0)`

Comment: I think it would be better to use [owner draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb775238#_win32_header_owner_draw) for the header control. In some circumstances the control may draw outside of `WM_PAINT` so your handler would not get called. On a side note, `SetWindowLongPtr` is a bad way of subclassing. [`SetWindowSubClass` is much safer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to send WM_SIZE to the Header window with wParam = SIZE_RESTORED and lParam = its own size, and found the Header line showed correctly.

Thanks to Remy Lebeau, I replaced LockWindowUpdate() with WM_SETREDRAW and improved performance of large lists. I read Raymond Chen articles on LockWindowUpdate() and understood the performance gain of WM_SETREDRAW for listview control come from bypassing "complex screen calculations". With the subclassed procedure some calculations need be redone. And sending WM_SIZE does the same job as resizing the window. The control shows perfectly without need to call InvalidateRect()/UpdateWindow().

Note: I changed the subclassing method using SetWindowLongPtr() into using SetWindowSubclass() but had no effect on my Header display issue.
I am sorting the list with all the 20 subitems, hence using virtual lists is not an option.